# jPopupMenu displaying way-off when window of application is moved

Tags: java, jpopupmenu

I am having somewhat of a problem with my jPopupMenu. When I run my project, everything loads correctly, there's no errors, the popupmenu works perfectly, the popupmenu is exactly where I want it when I rightclick.

However, when I move or resize the window of my application, and then rightclick to show my popupmenu, it shows up on the other side of the screen and/or way "offcourse". The more I move my window the more "offcourse" the popupmenu gets, any ideas?

I am using this code for my rightclick

```
    if(evt.isPopupTrigger())
    {
        jPopupMenu1.show(this, evt.getXOnScreen(), evt.getYOnScreen());
    }
```

Picture:

[misplaced popupmenu(?)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PrVC0.png)

EDIT: I might add that the popupmenu works correctly if I have my application maximized.

Comment: Are you looking for the JComponent to resize as well? or just the location?

Comment: I don't understand your question, sorry. I want the jPopupMenu to "follow" wherever I move the window of my application, if that makes any sense... I can't find anybody else with this problem nor any tutorials on how to fix it.

Like in Firefox (or whatever), when I move the window around I can still rightclick to get the popupmenu just at my mousecursor, no matter where the window is located. @DarkV1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anybody needs this...I figured it out.

The code I was using:

```
                                 if(evt.isPopupTrigger())
{
    jPopupMenu1.show(this, evt.getXOnScreen(), evt.getYOnScreen());
}
```

And the code that was needed:

```
                                if(evt.isPopupTrigger())
    {
        jPopup1.show(evt.getComponent(),
                       evt.getX(), evt.getY());
    }
```

This solved my issue with the popupmenu displaying on the other side of the screen/"offcourse".